# Is it possible to declare a Database as a variable?

Tags: sql, database, variables

I am working on data migration and want to be able to change my SourceDatabase  without eding the code in multiple places is this possible? This is what I have tried from looking at some other posts but I must be doing something wrong

```
Declare @SourceDatabase  VARCHAR(255)
Set @SourceDatabase = '[PrimaryTesting]';

Select  LAid+Dfeid as DFE,SchoolName from @SourceDatabase.dbo.School;
```

Comment: When asking database or SQL questions please specify the DBMS product you're using, Different platforms may have different syntaxes and different capabilities. You're more likely to get a timely and helpful answer if you provide accurate details.

Comment: You can do this using sqlcmd

Comment: Can you not generate the scripts for the entire database, and simply do a global replace of the database name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using MSSQL, in which case you'd have to build up the desired SQL string, then use the [`exec` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql) to run it:

```sql
declare @SourceDatabase VARCHAR(255) = '[PrimaryTesting]';

exec('select LAid+Dfeid as DFE,SchoolName from ' + @SourceDatabase + '.dbo.School;');
```

However, please be aware of the possible dangers of [SQL injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection) when using this approach.